# Format Exception (String was not recognized as a valid DateTime)

Tags: vb.net

I can't understand what is wrong with this code:

```
Date.ParseExact("9072019","dMMyyyy",CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat).ToString("d/MM/yyyy")
```

I want the integer value `9072019` to be converted to date value `9/07/2019`

Comment: Is `9/07/2019` July 9, or September 7? In your code, `"9072019","dMMyyyy"` makes it seem like July 9. Based on my local standard (US), `9/07/2019` would read September 7. So some ambiguity in your question needs some clearing up (the answers below interpret it differently.

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure there are enough characters to represent any date. You only leave one character for the day but what if instead of July 9, it's July 10? You would need another format string starting with `dd` for days 10-31. So let's format the string beforehand to have 8 characters, and use the appropriate string.

```vb
Dim i = 9072019
Dim s = i.ToString("00000000") ' now the string looks like "09072019"
Dim dt = Date.ParseExact(s, "dMMyyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)
```

You just need to ensure 8 digits in the string before it's parsed. @jmcilhinney answer does this more elegantly using PadLeft `i.ToString().PadLeft(8, "0"c)`. It appears your single `d` format string is fine

See [DateTime.ParseExact Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `9072019` isn't a valid `Date` in which is why you are getting an error like:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

To fix this, you need to make sure it's valid; it should be `09072019`.

You can use the [IsDate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.information.isdate?view=netframework-4.8) function to check whether or not it's valid...

```
If IsDate("09072019") Then
   ' Date/DateTime works fine here...
   Date.ParseExact("09072019", "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that either of the answers already provided actually address the issue here.  Check out this code:

```
Dim dateStrings = {"9072019", "09072019", "10072019"}
Dim formatStrings = {"dMMyyyy", "ddMMyyyy"}
Dim d As Date

For Each ds In dateStrings
    For Each fs In formatStrings
        If Date.TryParseExact(ds, fs, Nothing, DateTimeStyles.None, d) Then
            Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1}) => {2:MMMM d, yyyy}", ds, fs, d)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1}) => Invalid input", ds, fs)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

The output is as follows:

```
(9072019, dMMyyyy) => Invalid input
(9072019, ddMMyyyy) => Invalid input
(09072019, dMMyyyy) => July 9, 2019
(09072019, ddMMyyyy) => July 9, 2019
(10072019, dMMyyyy) => July 10, 2019
(10072019, ddMMyyyy) => July 10, 2019
```

As you can see, an input with a single-digit day fails to parse whether the format specifier includes one or two digits for the day, while inputs with double-digit days parse successfully in all cases.  Now check out this code:

```
Dim dateStrings = {"9/07/2019", "09/07/2019", "10/07/2019"}
Dim formatStrings = {"d/MM/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy"}
Dim d As Date

For Each ds In dateStrings
    For Each fs In formatStrings
        If Date.TryParseExact(ds, fs, Nothing, DateTimeStyles.None, d) Then
            Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1}) => {2:MMMM d, yyyy}", ds, fs, d)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1}) => Invalid input", ds, fs)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

The output is as follows:

```
(9/07/2019, d/MM/yyyy) => July 9, 2019
(9/07/2019, dd/MM/yyyy) => Invalid input
(09/07/2019, d/MM/yyyy) => July 9, 2019
(09/07/2019, dd/MM/yyyy) => July 9, 2019
(10/07/2019, d/MM/yyyy) => July 10, 2019
(10/07/2019, dd/MM/yyyy) => July 10, 2019
```

This time, the only combination that fails is the input with a single-digit day with the format specifier with a double-digit day.  Why does *"9/07/2019"* and *"d/MM/yyyy"* work when *"9072019"* and *"dMMyyyy"* don't?

Firstly, it's important to understand what a single-digit day in a format specifier actually means.  It doesn't mean that ONLY single digit days will be accepted in input.  It means that single-digit OR double-digit days will be accepted in input.  A double-digit day in a format specifier, on the other hand, means that ONLY double-digit days will be accepted in input.  *"d"* in a format specifier means *"9"*, *"09"* and *"10"* are all acceptable days while *"dd"* means that only *"09"* and *"10"* are acceptable.

The issue in the original code is that there are no delimiters in the input.  Because *"d"* means that either single-digit or double-digit days are accepted, an input of *"9072019"* gets parsed on the assumption that *"90"* is the day.  You might think the parsing algorithm should be smarter - maybe it could be - but it's not.  I'd say the reason for that is that there can be ambiguity.

Let's say that the input was *"1012019"* and the format specifier was *"dMMyyyy"*.  How does the algorithm tell the different between a valid input representing January 1, 2019 in *"dMMyyyy"* format and an invalid input representing January 10, 2019 in *"ddMyyyy"* format?  The fact is that it can't, so it doesn't try to.  Anything that could be ambiguous is simply rejected.

So, if you want to parse input without delimiters, you MUST use double digits for both input and format specifier, i.e. 8-digit and zero-padded days and months.  If you want to be able to omit the zero-padding then you MUST use delimiters.  The simplest answer to your specific case is to explicitly zero-pad the input in code, e.g.

```
Dim dateStrings = {"9072019", "09072019", "10072019"}
Dim formatStrings = {"dMMyyyy", "ddMMyyyy"}
Dim d As Date

For Each ds In dateStrings
    For Each fs In formatStrings
        If Date.TryParseExact(ds.PadLeft(8, "0"c), fs, Nothing, DateTimeStyles.None, d) Then
            Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1}) => {2:MMMM d, yyyy}", ds, fs, d)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1}) => Invalid input", ds, fs)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

The output is as follows:

```
(9072019, dMMyyyy) => July 9, 2019
(9072019, ddMMyyyy) => July 9, 2019
(09072019, dMMyyyy) => July 9, 2019
(09072019, ddMMyyyy) => July 9, 2019
(10072019, dMMyyyy) => July 10, 2019
(10072019, ddMMyyyy) => July 10, 2019
```